# CSS 3 Transform skewY and resize

Tags: html, css

Can someone explain how is this [site](http://davidparrelli.com/sites/olive/v1.0/index-home-1.html) achieving a perfect scaling of the skeyY transform object on resize?

I can achieve the static effect using the code bellow but I can not get it to maintain the perfect vertical alignment when resized. I tried using media queries but the results was not acceptable.

```css
.negociar {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
}

.skew-heading {
    
    background: #0A996F;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 11rem;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

    .skew-heading:after {
        background-color: white;
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        top: 100px;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
        -moz-transform: skewY(-9deg);
        -ms-transform: skewY(-9deg);
        -webkit-transform: skewY(-9deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 75% 0;
        -o-transform: skewY(-9deg);
        transform: skewY(-9deg);
        transform-origin: 75% 0;
        z-index: -1;
    }
```

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS please.

Comment: The question isn't very clear. I'm pretty sure you are talking about the angles... ? The prefixes are pretty distracting in this context. If you use codepen or something, you can use autoprefixr... that may cut out some possible errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VbpYqX

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
  </div>
</div>

.container {
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #56CCF2, #2F80ED) !important;
    position: relative;
}

.container:after {
    content: '';
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: white;
    transform: skewY(-9deg);
    transform-origin: top;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-9deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
}
```